# how to use dynamic orderBy into Postgresql with Prisma ORM?

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have a function to get users with orderBy. When I'm trying to use dynamic orderBy, I'm getting the wrong unsorted result. When I'm using static orderby like this **ORDER BY "acceptedInvites" asc** - it works well.
What is the problem?

```
export const getUsers = async (
page: number = 1,
pageSize: number = 10,
sortField: string = "acceptedInvites",
sortType: 'asc' | 'desc' = 'desc'

): Promise\<any\> =\> {
try {
const client = await getClient();
const skip = (page - 1) \* pageSize;
const total = await client.user.count()

`const orderBy = sortType === 'asc'
    ? `"${sortField}" ASC`
    : `"${sortField}" DESC`
    
    const users = await client.$queryRaw`
      SELECT
      "User".id,
      "User"."displayName",
      "User"."avatarUrl",
      "User"."isAvatar",
      COUNT("Referrals".id)::INTEGER as "acceptedInvites",
      "ReferredByUser"."displayName" as invitedBy,
      CAST(RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT("Referrals".id) DESC, "User"."displayName" ASC) AS INTEGER) as ranking
      FROM
        "User"
      LEFT JOIN
        "User" as "Referrals" ON "User"."id" = "Referrals"."referredBy"
      LEFT JOIN
        "User" as "ReferredByUser" ON "User"."referredBy" = "ReferredByUser"."id"
      GROUP BY
        "User".id, "User"."displayName", "ReferredByUser"."displayName"
        ORDER BY ${orderBy}
      OFFSET ${skip}
      LIMIT ${pageSize};
```

I'm trying to get sorted data using prisma queryRow

Comment: Because you are using capitals in your field names, you should surround the fieldnames with double quotes (`"`).  I think you dynamic version does not do that.   (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/JZW9mEer )

Comment: the same result when I added quotas
    const orderBy = sortType === 'asc'
    ? `"${sortField}" ASC`
    : `"${sortField}" DESC`

Answer (score 0):

this problem was about queryRaw does not support dynamic fields.
I needed using queryRawUnsafe instead

```
 try {
    const client = await getClient();
    const skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    const total = await client.user.count()

    const users = await client.$queryRawUnsafe(`
      SELECT
      "User".id,
      "User"."displayName",
      "User"."avatarUrl",
      "User"."isAvatar",
      COUNT("Referrals".id)::INTEGER as "acceptedInvites",
      "ReferredByUser"."displayName" as invitedBy,
      CAST(RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT("Referrals".id) DESC, "User"."displayName" ASC) AS INTEGER) as ranking
      FROM
        "User"
      LEFT JOIN
        "User" as "Referrals" ON "User"."id" = "Referrals"."referredBy"
      LEFT JOIN
        "User" as "ReferredByUser" ON "User"."referredBy" = "ReferredByUser"."id"
      GROUP BY
        "User".id, "User"."displayName", "ReferredByUser"."displayName"
        ORDER BY ${sortField} ${sortType}
      OFFSET ${skip}
      LIMIT ${pageSize};
`);
    return {
      users,
      total
    }
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw APIError('Error while getUsers', HttpStatusCode.INTERNAL_SERVER, err.message ?? err);
  }
```